# How to run OpenMP in WSL?

Tags: openmp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some binaries from c++ codes supporting Openmp under linux system. I want to run them in the WSL（Windows Subsystem for Linux) on my windows 10. I think I should install some packages to support Openmp. What do I need to install? Follow the windows openmp installation routine to install intel c++ complier? Or ubuntu routine to install a high version gcc? Maybe both? (Then my system disk may not have enough space.)

In case my above question is ill-conditioned, I illustrate my question more detailed as below. I would like to know if I have a binary supporting Openmp. Is it necessary for me to install any package to use it? Could I only set the env "OMP_NUM_THREADS" and use it directly? If I have c++ codes to compile a binary supporting Openmp. What do I need to install under WSL?

I couldn't find an easy tutorial about the openmp under WSL. Forgive my ignorance. Could you give me suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: OpenMP is usually implemented as a combination of compiler support and a runtime library. You may be missing the latter. Use `ldd` on your executables to see if their dynamic library dependencies are all satisfied and if not use the Linux package manager to install them. Most likely you'll need `libgomp` (the GCC OpenMP runtime) or `libomp5` (the Intel/LLVM OpenMP runtime).

Comment: @HristoIliev minor typo: the Intel runtime is linked to as "libiomp5.so", while the LLVM one (although built from effectively the same code, and interface compatible) is distributed as "libomp.so"  (so there is no "libomp5").

Comment: @JimCownie, the Ubuntu package for LLVM's runtime is called `libomp5`. And Ubuntu is the distro most likely to be installed in WSL.

Comment: @HristoIliev Ah. OK. I am discussing the name fo the file, not whatever someone decided to call the package :-)

Comment: @JimCownie I should've made it clearer that I switched the context from libraries to packages providing them.

Comment: Thank you for all of you to clarify the package name or library name. All I need seems to be a runtime part of OPENMP